# Rails 4 conditional includes of has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 classes connected by a join model

```
class Table
  has_many :chairs
  has_many :people, through: :chairs
end

class Chair
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :chair
end

class People
  has_many :chairs
  has_many :tables, through: :chairs
  scope :not_paid, -> { where(paid: false) }
end
```

I'd like to eager load Tables where the People hasn't paid, so I used this:

```
class Table
  has_many :unpaid_people, -> { People.not_paid }, through: :chairs, source: :people
end

Table.includes(:unpaid_people).where(...)
```

But that gives the following error:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "people"
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Are you aware of goldiloader? I'm not sure if it would work in this case, or if you would even want to use it if did.

Comment: When I'm trying to sort out messy join problems, I usually start by using `to_sql` on the scope to see what weird SQL Rails is trying to build with it... that will often help you spot the problem, which you can solve by figuring out what SQL it really needs to build to return what you want... then backporting that fix into the rails/ruby code. So what happens when you do `Table.unpaid_people.to_sql` ?